# How to add server timestamp in custom java object, to store it in Firestore?

Tags: android, firebase

To upload a custom java object to `Firebase Firestore`, I want to have a field created `time` , which will store the server timestamp when the data is created. how to do it ?

Comment: please post your object that you want to send to firebase

Comment: I don't think there is any such functionality.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the solution @alex_mamo . However, I have solved it on my own. The solution is the same as you maintain in the solved solution.

Answer (score 2):

To [write a server-side timestamp in Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#server_timestamp) you need to use this marker value: `FieldValue.serverTimestamp()`. So if you want a specific field in a Java object to have this value, initialize that field to `FieldValue.serverTimestamp()`.

```
public class MyObject {
    public String value;
    public Object timestamp = FieldValue.serverTimestamp();
}
```

I've marked the `timestamp` field as an `Object`, since (I think) it'll have a different type on initial creation than it does when you read it back from the database.

Answer (score -1):

First you have to fetch your server time and then you can upload that time to firebase real time database.

your custom data class:

```
public class ServerTime {

    public String time;

    public ServerTime (String time) {
        this.time= time;
    }
}

ServerTime object = ServerTime(timestamp); // set your time here
DatabaseReference mRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
        .getReference("ServerTime").setValue(object);
```

Comment: This doesn't set the time from the server, which is what he's asking for

Comment: To set time from server first @Shuvendu Dhal need to fetch server time and then he push that to firebase.

Comment: Which then wouldn't be accurate enough for many uses, as an unknown amount of time passed between the two events. Normal sql dbs can do this atomically, but I'm not sure firebase can

Answer (score -1):

You connot do it from client library. You need to create a Cloud function, that triggers when value was added to firestore collection, and insert current date field to it.
[More about Firebase cloud functions and Firestore triggers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events)